# Why is my USB to HDMI adapter no longer working after a firmware update?

Tags: windows-10, usb, display, hdmi, external-display

I have one of these [USB to HDMI adapters](https://www.amazon.fr/Cablelera-Adaptateur-Moniteur-Convertisseur-Compatible/dp/B0BLHB5JLW); “Cablelera Adaptateur USB vers HDMI, USB 3.0/2.0 vers HDMI Audio Vidéo Vidéo HD 1080P Convertisseur pour PC, Ordinateur Portable HDTV Compatible avec Windows XP/10/8/7 (NO Mac & Vista), Small”

[image]

I was doing a firmware update and I accidentally unplugged it so now it is no longer working and is not recognized by my PC.

Comment: Have you reinstalled the drivers?

Comment: Can you link to an English version of the product specifications?

Comment: @Ramhound It's just another DisplayLink based adapter.

Comment: @Ramhound changed the url to `.co.uk` instead of `.fr` : https://www.amazon.co.uk/Cablelera-Adaptateur-Moniteur-Convertisseur-Compatible/dp/B0BLHB5JLW?th=1

Comment: Which firmware have you updated - the UEFI/BIOS?

Comment: Also try removing the device from USB history in the Registry. Windows will fine it when it's plugged in, and look for a driver. See also https://www.itechtics.com/remove-traces-usb-drives-ever-connected-computer/

Comment: @ChanganAuto  yes i tried but still not working.

Answer (score 3):

You probably bricked it. Some devices don't have appropriate safeguards in their firmware update procedures, so if you unplug it in the middle of a firmware update, the new firmware may have only been written partway, leaving the overall firmware image corrupted and unusable. Check with the vendor for recovery procedures, but it might be irrecoverably bricked.

Comment: The instructions for every firmware update say 'do not power off or remove during update' - you now have an object that appears to look like a usb to hdmi adapter but nothing else. Pray to the Amazon gods,(search for another)  throw them some money, and then bask in the glory of experience, and vow never to pull out too early.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the driver did not get installed properly.

If the only thing you changed prior to it stopping to work;

1. Open Device Manager (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).
2. Find the Firmware tab and open it.
3. Open the one you recently updated (double click).
4. Driver Tab.
5. Roll Back Driver (middle option).

Then reboot and it should work. Then re-do the installation of the firmware.

Comment: The adapter had it's own graphic interface and i saw it had an update while it was updating i unplugged it . Now when i plug it back i can't find it on device manager so I can't roll back .